# flutter macos build missing binary library file when run on codemagic but included locally

Tags: flutter, macos, build, codemagic

I'm building a flutter app that uses the realm package.
When building on my local machine with `flutter build macos --release` the resulting app is working fine.

However, when building on codemagic, the build is missing `librealm_dart.dylib` inside the *.app folder and the resulting app crashes upon startup.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
dyld[48302]: Library not loaded: @rpath/librealm_dart.dylib
  Referenced from: <8FDD2B77-17E3-3688-BCB1-9EF31099437D> /Applications/<app name redacted>.app/Contents/Frameworks/realm.framework/Versions/A/realm
  Reason: tried: '/Applications/<app name redacted>/Contents/Frameworks/librealm_dart.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/<app name redacted>/Contents/Frameworks/realm.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/librealm_dart.dylib' (no such file),
... (it keeps on listing paths)
```

The strange thing is that if I run the build sequence twice on codemagic, right after each other, it works and the library is included in the resulting *.app.

This is won't work:

```
# Setup a new keychain
keychain initialize

# Fetch signing files
app-store-connect fetch-signing-files "<redacted>" --type MAC_APP_STORE --platform MAC_OS --create

# Mac installer distribution certificates
app-store-connect create-certificate --type MAC_INSTALLER_DISTRIBUTION --save
app-store-connect list-certificates --type MAC_INSTALLER_DISTRIBUTION --save
        
# Set up signing certificates
keychain add-certificates

# Set up code signing settings on Xcode project
xcode-project use-profiles

flutter build macos --release --build-number=$(($PROJECT_BUILD_NUMBER + 151))
        
# Package application
set -x
APP_NAME=$(find $(pwd) -name ios -prune -o -name "*.app" -print)
cd $(dirname "$APP_NAME")
PACKAGE_NAME=$(basename "$APP_NAME" .app).pkg

# Create unsigned package
xcrun productbuild --component "$APP_NAME" /Applications/ unsigned.pkg

# Installer cert
INSTALLER_CERT_NAME=$(keychain list-certificates \
  | jq '[.[]
    | select(.common_name
    | contains("Mac Developer Installer"))
    | .common_name][0]' \
      | xargs)
        
# Sign the package
xcrun productsign --sign "$INSTALLER_CERT_NAME" unsigned.pkg "$PACKAGE_NAME"
rm -f unsigned.pkg
```

This is working perfectly:

```
# Setup a new keychain
keychain initialize

# Fetch signing files
app-store-connect fetch-signing-files "<redacted>" --type MAC_APP_STORE --platform MAC_OS --create

# Mac installer distribution certificates
app-store-connect create-certificate --type MAC_INSTALLER_DISTRIBUTION --save
app-store-connect list-certificates --type MAC_INSTALLER_DISTRIBUTION --save
        
# Set up signing certificates
keychain add-certificates

# Set up code signing settings on Xcode project
xcode-project use-profiles

flutter build macos --release --build-number=$(($PROJECT_BUILD_NUMBER + 151))
        
# Package application
set -x
APP_NAME=$(find $(pwd) -name ios -prune -o -name "*.app" -print)
cd $(dirname "$APP_NAME")
PACKAGE_NAME=$(basename "$APP_NAME" .app).pkg

# Create unsigned package
xcrun productbuild --component "$APP_NAME" /Applications/ unsigned.pkg

# Installer cert
INSTALLER_CERT_NAME=$(keychain list-certificates \
  | jq '[.[]
    | select(.common_name
    | contains("Mac Developer Installer"))
    | .common_name][0]' \
      | xargs)
        
# Sign the package
xcrun productsign --sign "$INSTALLER_CERT_NAME" unsigned.pkg "$PACKAGE_NAME"
rm -f unsigned.pkg

# Setup a new keychain
keychain initialize

# Fetch signing files
app-store-connect fetch-signing-files "<redacted>" --type MAC_APP_STORE --platform MAC_OS --create

# Mac installer distribution certificates
app-store-connect create-certificate --type MAC_INSTALLER_DISTRIBUTION --save
app-store-connect list-certificates --type MAC_INSTALLER_DISTRIBUTION --save
        
# Set up signing certificates
keychain add-certificates

# Set up code signing settings on Xcode project
xcode-project use-profiles

flutter build macos --release --build-number=$(($PROJECT_BUILD_NUMBER + 151))
        
# Package application
set -x
APP_NAME=$(find $(pwd) -name ios -prune -o -name "*.app" -print)
cd $(dirname "$APP_NAME")
PACKAGE_NAME=$(basename "$APP_NAME" .app).pkg

# Create unsigned package
xcrun productbuild --component "$APP_NAME" /Applications/ unsigned.pkg

# Installer cert
INSTALLER_CERT_NAME=$(keychain list-certificates \
  | jq '[.[]
    | select(.common_name
    | contains("Mac Developer Installer"))
    | .common_name][0]' \
      | xargs)
        
# Sign the package
xcrun productsign --sign "$INSTALLER_CERT_NAME" unsigned.pkg "$PACKAGE_NAME"
rm -f unsigned.pkg
```

I tried debugging and couldn't find the issue so far.

Does anyone have an idea what's missing on codemagic? Because locally it's working.

Answer (score 1):

try to check if you added it to `Linked Frameworks & Libraries` section of the target in Xcode. And you use the same target when archive from Xcode and with `flutter build` command

Comment: I checked and it's correctly set-up. Strangely, the build succeeds if I let it run twice on codemagic, right after each other. This is a workaround but not the solution I'd like. I edited my question to reflect that. Do you have any idea why that might be?